# I would like to know the textbook/paper on hamiltonian for rf-SQUID

Tags: resource-request, superconducting-quantum-computing, annealing, hamiltonian

I am a graduate student in the Department of Computer Engineering, and I am currently doing research on superconducting quantum computers. In particular, I am focusing on quantum annealing machines and working on building a simulation environment for quantum annealing machines.

In order to simulate the quantum mechanical behavior of quantum annealing machines, we need to know the Hamiltonian of superconducting quantum circuits, so I investigated the Hamiltonian of real machines by reading the following paper from D-Wave.

- [Experimental Demonstration of a Robust and Scalable Flux Qubit](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4321)
- [Experimental Investigation of an Eight Qubit Unit Cell in a Superconducting Optimization Processor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1628)
- [A Compound Josephson Junction Coupler for Flux Qubits With Minimal
  Crosstalk](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3784)

From these references, we have been able to grasp the structure of the quantum annealing machine. However, because the paper introduces a Hamiltonian in the descent,
In particular, the equations for the rf-SQUID (made by compound Josephson junction or compound-compound Josephson junction) that makes up the qubit are difficult to understand.

What knowledge do I need to understand the Hamiltonian of this qubit? And I would like you to suggest a suitable textbook/paper. I have studied computer science, basic quantum mechanics, statistical mechanics, and quantum information.

Also, if possible, I would like to know if there is a tool that can simulate a superconducting quantum circuit taking into account the applied flux bias.

Comment: Does [scQubit](https://scqubits.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3/) do the job of the tool you are looking for?

Comment: I know that tool can simulate the original circuit including the external magnetic flux, but can it also take into account the mutual inductance between the qubit and the coupler?

Comment: Does [WRSpice](http://wrcad.com/wrspice.html) do the job of the tool you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't know there is a SPICE tool that could also handle Josephson Junction. I would like to investigate how to use this tool.
Thank you very much.